# Python 2.7 ctrl+c undeterministic behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

I'd like a correct <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> handling in my script, I've been reading some examples but I cannot achieve a deterministic behaviour.
For example, given following script:

```
  1 import signal
  2 import time
  3
  4 def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
  5     raise Exception('captured ctrl+c')
  6
  7 signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
  8
  9 c = True
 10 while c:
 11     try:
 12         pass
 13     except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
 14         print 'captured keyboardexception'
 15         print str(e)
 16     except Exception as e:
 17         print 'captured exception'
 18         print str(e)
 19         c = False
```

I can get these two different outputs

```
$ python ctrlc.py
^Ccaptured exception
captured ctrl+c

$ python ctrlc.py
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "ctrlc.py", line 12, in <module>
    pass
  File "ctrlc.py", line 5, in sigint_handler
    raise Exception('captured ctrl+c')
Exception: captured ctrl+c
```

I've tried different configs, also with double exception handling and without the signal handling but you can always get different beahaviours hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classic race condition. with your loop unrolled, it looks like this:

```
while True:
    ....
    try:
       pass      <-----
    ....

while True:      <-----
    ....
    try:
        pass
```

In the time between the arrows, you are actually not in a try/except clause. So you should expect two different behaviours.

Try this:

```
try:
    while True:
         pass
except....
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what whats happening in my real script. ctrl+c was hit before entering the try

Answer (score 1):

I suggest responding to the [`CTRL_C_EVENT` signal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.CTRL_C_EVENT):

> The signal corresponding to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keystroke event. This signal can only be used with os.kill().

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: @hithwen: isn't CTRL+C the event that you wish to respond to?

Comment: In theory I don't need to handle any signal, just to capture KeyboardInterrupt (or Base exception), I added the signal handling in  the example to have different messages depending on execution path. I should handle CTRL_C_EVENT in the example